# Cannot Extract Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client.Feature.DisplayName Property

Tags: powershell, csom, feature, feature-activation

I've written a CSOM script for Powershell (code below) to enumerate the features activated on a given site. When in the `foreach` loop I use `$f.DefinitionId`, I get a list of the feature GUIDs... however if I swap this for `$f.DisplayName` it outputs nothing (no errors).

I'm confused as to how this can be because the DisplayName property is listed on the class reference for MS.SP.Client.Feature and is picked up as a valid choice by the Powershell ISE IntelliSense.

Have tried it on two different tenants (the former where I have site collection admin only; the latter where I have full tenant admin) both with the same result.

EDIT: I checked the output of `$f` with `Select-Object` and it appears `DisplayName` is there, just blank... so any idea why? I had tried assigning `$f.DisplayName` to a variable and loading it via `$ctx.Load` but this produces a 'cannot find an overload' error.

[image]

Any ideas?

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll';
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll';

$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString;
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials("admin@xxx.onmicrosoft.com", $password);
$siteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/";

$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl);
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials;

$thisSite = $ctx.Web;
$ctx.Load($thisSite);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

$fList = $thisSite.Features;
$ctx.load($fList);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach ($f in $fList) {
    $ctx.load($f)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $f.DisplayName
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly load the display name property of the feature. In CSOM unlike SSOM, it (mostly) only gives you only the properties that you ask for.

Try either of the below two approaches, should work:

```
foreach ($f in $fList) {
    $f.Retrieve("DisplayName")  
    $ctx.load($f)   
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $f.DisplayName
}
```

Or

```
foreach ($f in $fList) {
    $f.Retrieve("DisplayName")  
    $ctx.load($f)   
    $ctx.load($f.DisplayName)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $f.DisplayName
}
```

Reference for part 1 - [Get SharePoint Online Site and Web Feature using CSOM and PowerShell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34537.get-sharepoint-online-site-and-web-feature-using-csom-and-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Second one I'd already tried to no avail, but the first one works, cheers!